# Дочерние строки таблицы с использованием bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно сделать что бы в таблице можно было нажать на строку и появлялись несколько скрытых строк этой же таблицы. Так как я использую bootstrap для разработки, то мне хотелось бы сделать это средствами botstrap collapse plugin, а не сочинять свой плагин. Я нашла рабочий пример в котором именно то, что мне нужно.
Ссылка на пример: http://www.bootply.com/GGAMvot45f

Проблема в том что этот пример корректно работает только для младших версий bootstrap (3.1-3.2). При использовании более старших версий (на данный момент у меня подключена 4-я версия), работает некорректно - вместо нескольких строк появляется только одна первая. Я видела множество решений где предлагается обернуть выпадающий контент в див и новую таблицу, но тогда получается что у меня таблица в ячейке, выравнивание у родительского и дочерних столбцов совершенно разное. А хочется именно как в примере по ссылке, т.е. столбец под столбцом.

Вот пример где с тем же кодом но с другой версией bootstrap уже не работает, точнее работает частично, выводится одна подстрока таблицы вместо двух.

http://www.bootply.com/43bMNy559z

Comment: С помощью бутстарпа сделать не получилось, но хотелось бы выделить решение которое мне понравилось, вдруг кому-нибудь понадобится.

Ссылка на [статью](http://webdesignerhut.com/data-table-with-collapsible-table-rows/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И для третьего, и для четвёртого бутстрапа работает [пример из документации](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example), если завернуть группы строк в `tbody` и сворачивать-разворачивать именно `tbody`.

Для этого для `tbody` надо назначить `id` и класс `collapse`, а для управляющей строки - `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="id с решёткой"`. Бутстрап [просит не забывать](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-collapse-accessibility) про `aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="id без решётки">` для строки-переключателя.

Четвёртый бутстрап [пока ещё криво работает](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18060) с `tbody`, но это лечится добавлением небольшого фрагмента из стилей третьего бутстрапа:

```
tbody.collapse.in {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

Глифовские иконки в четвёртом бутстрапе пока не подцепляются. Возьмём их аналог из [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/).

Проверьте результат:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
/* fix = code from bootstrap 3 */
tbody.collapse.in {
  display: table-row-group;
}
</style>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column</th><th>Column</th><th>Column</th><th>Column</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-1">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td>data</td>
       <td>data</td>  
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="group-of-rows-1" class="collapse">
    <tr>
      <td>- child row</td>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>- child row</td>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-2">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="group-of-rows-2" class="collapse">
    <tr>
      <td>- child row</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>- child row</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

http://www.bootply.com/Qyh5hbEMdU

Answer (score 0):

В [руководстве](http://www.bootstrap-tutorials.com/bootstrap4tutorials/Bootstrap-4-collapse-tutorials.php) от разработчиков Bootstrap все корректно работает, насколько я могу понять вашу проблему.

Comment: наверное вопрос был задан не очень правильно, теперь есть наглядный пример где именно не работает

Comment: Я понял вашу проблему, вижу решение только в виде того, что бы самим регулировать отступы. Для этого потребуется в стилях прописать более весомое правило, чем правило в bootstrap стиле.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Стараюсь так и делать, учту ваше пожелание. Просто изначально вопрос был не до конца точно и конкретно сформулирован, в следствии чего я предоставил общее решение (в данном случае указателем на конкретный раздел документации), как правильно использовать данную технологию.